# How to use RoboPods with LibGDX

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm, chartboost

I have built a game with LibGDX and I want to integrate Chartboost within the iOS version. I am using RoboVM to get it onto iOS. They recently came out with RoboPods: https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master

They say all you have to do is add one dependency to your gradle and that is it. Do I still have to add the 10 lines of code that you typically would with Chartboost within Xcode?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement the roboPod.